# Solution cannot be deserialized because it does not have a public default constructor

Tags: 2013, visual-studio-2012, solution-deployment, retraction

I am currently trying to deploy a timer job to my SharePoint site. for the first deployment I forgot to implement a  public default constructor for the Timer Job Class. And now I am stuck because I cannot retract the old solution and update it with the newer one with the public default constructor implemented.

I have already tried it with the Manage farm solutions page and got an error like this:

[image]

I have also tried this one here:

```
Uninstall-SPSolution -Identity testproject.wsp -allwebapplications
Remove-SPSolution -Identity testproject.wsp -force
```

With the same error and I am driving crazy right know because I don't know any more solutions to handle this error.

Can anyone tell me how I can "kill" the corrupted solution from my farm so that I can deploy the correct one?

EDIT:
I have also tried the "Update-SPSolution" but get the same error...

Comment: Have you tried Update-SPSolution  ?

Comment: @Sudhakar yes and I am getting the same message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snickbrack,

Please try to copy your DLL to GAC directly. 
You can do this manually or use some VS plugins like CKSDev or Fishbone

Comment: Yes, this made it! I have done it with CKSDev and Mavention. Thanks